# After npm successfully start ,localhost is only showing source code of that page homepage.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

[this is my server.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F10we.png)
[this is showing in loalhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQhxZ.png)

Comment: You're literally telling express to send the entire file on lines 21-24 of your code. Send file literally sends the file. If you're trying to render something to the webpage, you need to send an html file where the JS can be run from.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are serving the `homepage.js` file to client when instead what you should probably do is build the react app into some `public` or `build` folder and serve the `index.html` file